# Python and forcing the download of a file

Tags: python, python-requests

I currently have the below code wich works great as long as the response on the `GET` has the `content-disposition` header. However the problem comes in when there is no header. Normally this would indicate viewing the file in the browser. Is there a way to force the download from within python?

```
def action_download(doc_list):
    i = 0
    for doc in doc_list:
        try:
            r = requests.get(doc)
            filename = re.search('filename="(.*)"', r.headers['content-disposition']).group(1)
            with open(filename, "w") as code:
                i += 1
                code.write(r.content)
                code.close()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print '\nError: File Not Found Server Side'
            print doc
        except Exception:
            print '\nUnknown Error'
            print doc
            print r.headers
            traceback.print_exc()
            continue
    if i < 1:
        sys.exit()
```

**UPDATED CODE BASED ON RESPONSES**

Defining the filename and passing the data content via hte write fucntion works perfectly. Updated code below for anyone coming across the problem.

*Note the addition in the `KeyError` exception.

```
def action_download(doc_list):
    i = 0
    for doc in doc_list:
        try:
            r = requests.get(doc)
            filename = re.search('filename="(.*)"', r.headers['content-disposition']).group(1)
            with open(filename, "w") as code:
                i += 1
                code.write(r.content)
                code.close()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print '\nError: File Not Found Server Side'
            print doc
        except KeyError:
            temp = str(doc).rsplit('.', 1)[1]
            ext = re.sub(r'\?.*', r'', temp)
            filename = "file{}.{}".format(i, ext.replace('?T', ''))
            with open(filename, "w") as code:
                i += 1
                code.write(r.content)
                code.close()
            continue
        except Exception:
            print '\nUnknown Error'
            print doc
            print r.headers
            traceback.print_exc()
            continue
    if i < 1:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: If there's no filename given in the response headers, just make up your own filename; for example from the last part of the URL.

Comment: Yip works fine if I defined the filename (which thinking about it now is rather obvious. Kudos to hindsight bias ^_^)

Comment: Do you want to suggest the above comment as an `answer`, ill give it the big green tick ^_^